# Changing content type machine name in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a Drupal 6 site with ~ 400 nodes of content type "page". Over the last couple years, we've added quite a few fields that apply only to products, but we never split those products into their own content type. So, I have approximately 350 nodes that are products, and 50 that are general content, all within the same "page" content type. Because we have so many fields that apply only to the product nodes, I'd now like to split them out into their own content type.

Here's the problem: because most of the nodes are products, it'd be easiest to rename the existing "page" type to "product", and then create a new type called "page". (After that, I'd just need to re-create the 50 general content pages in the new "page" type.) But after I renamed the first type and created the new "page" type, "page" didn't show up in the content type list. I'm assuming I've run into a conflict created by changing machine names, but I'm not sure where the conflict is. I tried flushing all caches, but that didn't seem to help.

At this point, I've reverted back to my backup, and I'm trying to figure out a better way to do it. Perhaps if I change the human-readable names, but leave the machine names alone? It's a bit confusing if you have to rely on the machine names that don't match up, but it seems it would work.

Is there a better way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what the issue is exactly without more information, but I'd suggest shying away from renaming `Page` since it's a core content type.  Just create your new "product" type and go from there.  It shouldn't be all that hard to move your product nodes into the new type if you've got access to the DB.

Comment: So far, I've stayed away from manual changes to the dbase. Is it as simple as changing the `type` column in the `node` table?

Comment: Sure thing Mark.  Also, here's another question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902562/is-it-possible-to-change-the-content-type-on-nodes-in-drupal-6